# not getting the value from outside render function

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react. please help me.
i am trying the get a value of data outside render.

```
data.map(

       <button onClick = { () => { console.log (data)}}></button>
   )
```

i am getting the value of data here. but

```
  handleClick = () => { 
       console.log (data)  ///  not getting the value
     }

  <button onClick = { this.handleClick}></button>
```

if i try this.hadleClick , then i am not getting any value. why . thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not passing the value to your `handleClick` function. A couple options:

Bind the function with the params in your `onClick`:

```
data.map(
    <button onClick = { this.handleClick.bind(this, data) }></button>
)
```

Pass an anonymous function to your click handler:

```
data.map(
    <button onClick = { () => this.handleClick(data) }></button>
)
```

And you'll need to update your `handleClick` function to accept `data` as a param:

```
handleClick = data => { 
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the data you want to print to the function like below:

```
<button onClick = { () => this.handleClick(data) }></button>
```

(and your handler function should accept it as well)

```
handleClick = (data) => console.log(data);
```